# Laravel INSERT query adding irrelevant columns, making the query fail

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, sql-update, sql-insert

The error I am being presented with is:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in
>   'field list' (SQL: update `companies` set `user_id` = 3, `updated_at`
>   = 2014-03-16 14:59:56 where `id` = 1)

But my code shouldn't have an UPDATE query, it's a new INSERT! Also, if you look at the table structure below, there is no 'user_id' field, which it's trying to set?

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `town` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `logo_file_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_file_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_content_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The INSERT query which appears to be failing:

```
public function postCreate(){
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

        if($validator->passes()){

            $user               = new User;
            $user->firstname    = Input::get('firstname');
            $user->surname      = Input::get('surname');
            $user->phone_number = Input::get('phone_number');
            $user->email        = Input::get('email');
            $user->password     = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

            $user->save();

            $insertedId = $user->id;
            $user = User::where('id','=', $insertedId)->first();
            $user->attachRole(2);

            $company                =   new Company;
            $company->company_name  =   Input::get('company_name');
            $company->address_1     =   Input::get('address_1');
            $company->town          =   Input::get('town');
            $company->postcode      =   Input::get('postcode');
            $company->phone_number  =   Input::get('phone_number');
            $company->approved      =   '0';
            $company                =   Company::create(['logo' => Input::file('logo')]);

            $user->company()->save($company);
```

The user section works perfectly. However, the Company side of things appears to be failing. I'm not sure why it is updating the Companies' table, when it should be inserting.

For the logo, I am using [Stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler#overview). When I check the log on the error, this is the last MYSQL command -

```
insert into `companies` (`logo_file_name`, `logo_file_size`, `logo_content_type`,

`logo_updated_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('2012-12-07 16.31.42.png', '36952',

'image/png', '2014-03-16 14:59:56', '2014-03-16 14:59:56', '2014-03-16 14:59:56')
```

It's as if Laravel is bypassing the first pieces of information!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The line that creates the company with the logo overwrites the above loaded attributes of $company, so when you save the company it is updating it as it has been loaded when creating it.

Comment: By commenting that line out, it is still trying to find the user_id field, that doesn't exist. - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `companies` (`company_name`, `address_1`, `town`, `postcode`, `phone_number`, `approved`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test Company, Test Address, London, CD5 GBT, 07958684756, 0, 3, 2014-03-16 15:21:48, 2014-03-16 15:21:48)).

Comment: Post company relation defined in User model.

Comment: public function company()
 {
  return $this->hasOne('Company');
 }

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, try changing the variable name 'company' as it might be confusing Laravel.

Comment: I deleted the logo line, and changed the 'save' command to -> $company->save(); This now adds the fields. However, it now leaves the logo fields blank!

Comment: This adds the fields, but it adds the logo onto a new row -    $company->approved  =   '0';

   $company->save();

   $company = Company::create(['logo' => Input::file('logo')]);  
   $company->save(); - Any advice on adding it to the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the company first and then save it. It will create only one row, then you can associate it to the user.

```
$company = Company::create(['logo' => Input::file('logo')]); 
$company->approved = '0'; 
$company->save();
```